# No eligible devices for app install. | Android | Oreo 8.1.0

Tags: android, google-play, android-8.1-oreo

I am getting this message in google play store -

[image]

**Here is the Manifest of this app -**

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />


<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

**Gradle config -**

```
defaultConfig {
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 27
versionCode 5
versionName "1.0"
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Comment: Please check if you have restricted your app  in the store listing with device specific in 
 publish play store console. May be device with which your play store  account is linked is restricted.

Comment: @DonnyDominic I can install the app on other phones, getting this issue in Alcatel phone Oreo version.

Comment: Shoeb your configuration is correct  in manifest file. Try to clear the cache in google play services app.of your alcatel phone. [try this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3uXnztSwGI)

Comment: @DonnyDominic - Alright let me try now!

Answer (score 1):

This may be possible if the store listing is not done correctly, you may want to check your application on the Playstore console to make sure you have correctly completed all the requirements.

You may also refer to this link for further information about the eligibilty of devices on Google Playstore

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/play/06KeBKHNrv0/XoNKJy8OAQAJ

Comment: I can install the app on other phones, getting this issue in Alcatel phone Oreo version.

Comment: Then please refer to the link I have attached, it shows the possible issues associated to the device you must be using

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the apk you uploaded was compiled for arm architecture, but your phone is using x86 architecture, or vice versa.
To fix it you can up the apk version, generate signed apk again, choose the missing "flavor" (x86 or arm) and upload that apk to the same release in the dev console.